# How to solve TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface?

Tags: python

My code:

```
big_int = 536870912
f = open('sample.txt', 'wb')

for item in range(0, 10):
   y = bytearray.fromhex('{:0192x}'.format(big_int))
   f.write("%s" %y)
f.close()
```

I want to convert a long int to bytes. But I am getting `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

Comment: just try doing `f.write(y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, strings are implicitly Unicode and are therefore detached from a specific binary representation (which depends on the encoding that is used).  Therefore, the string `"%s" % y` cannot be written to a file that is opened in binary mode.

Instead, you can just write `y` directly to the file:

```
y = bytearray.fromhex('{:0192x}'.format(big_int))
f.write(y)
```

Moreover, your code (`"%s" % y`) in fact creates a Unicode string containing the *string representation* of `y` (i.e., `str(y)`), which isn't what you think it is.  For example:

```
>>> '%s' % bytearray()
"bytearray(b'')"
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Will answer, it is better to use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement in to open your files. Also, if you using python 3.2 and later, you can use [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) or [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) to reverse the process.

Sample of what I said:

```
big_int=536870912

with open('sample.txt', 'wb') as f:
    y = big_int.to_bytes((big_int.bit_length() // 8) + 1, byteorder='big')
    f.write(y)
    print(int.from_bytes(y, byteorder='big'))
```

The last `print` is to show you how to reverse it.

Comment: Just to add: the reason why `with` is "better" is because it automatically closes the file when the scope is ended, even when an exception is raised in the middle.